# open(const char *path, int oflag ) doesn't accept path like "~/my.log"

Tags: linux, io, posix

I tried using

```
open("~/my.log",  O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,
        S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)
```

to create a file, but it returns error

```
"No such file or directory".
```

Is it because that open() does not translate "~"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It is the shell that translates `~`, not `open`. The same goes for wildcard characters like `*` and `?`. In fact, any time you can type anything other than exactly the bytes that are on disk for a filename, it is your shell that is translating into an actual filename for you.

Comment: I roughly remember fopen() can handle such path names, right?

Comment: @SetTimer: No, fopen() is not using the shell either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly.

The tilde is part of the shell path name expansion. The open library call does not use the shell.

Comment: In shell, `~/my.log` is the same as `"$HOME/my.log"`. You can get `HOME` environment variable in C and use it to construct the desired path. See [`getenv()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/).

Answer (score 1):

You could either (as [Palec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2157640/palec) commented), construct (using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) with [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html), i.e. `getenv("HOME")`) the desired path, or use the [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) function to expand `"~/my.log"` to the desired path. See also [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) with `GLOB_TILDE`

So you could code:

```
char logpathbuf[256];
snprintf (logpathbuf, sizeof(logpathbuf), "%s/my.log", getenv("HOME"));
int fd = open(logpathbuf,  O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,
              S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
if (fd <0) { perror("open logfile"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

<sup>except that this code could misbehave or crash in the unlikely case of a missing `HOME` or too long `HOME` in your environment. See [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)</sup>

BTW, you might be interested by [openlog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openlog.3.html) and [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openlog.3.html)

Your `open("~/my.log", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777)` would actually work in the unfortunate case where you have a directory exactly named `~`; this could be possible by running the `mkdir \~` shell command before (the backslash asks the shell to not interpret or expand the following tilde), but nobody would like to make such a bad trick.